# iPhone 4s does not synch with iTunes 9.2.1

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, powerbook, itunes

I have iTunes 9.2.1 on a G4 PPC Powerbook and new iPhone 4s (Sept 2012) does not appear in the device list to synch music with Powerbook.

Answer (score 1):

Synching with your iPhone requires iTunes 10.7 or higher, assuming you're running iOS 6+. See [this page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To sync you will need to have an Intel Mac running OS X 10.6 or later

Comment: right. That too.